# I can't edit tb_gateway.yaml

Tags: thingsboard

While I'm Trying to edit GW_ACCESS_TOKEN it says permission denied [image]

I'm using raspberry pi 4 with raspian operating system and I have novice knowloge of using raspberry pi

I tried to modify the file to add my token but it's not able to be modified